# TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER возвращает нуль на 5.1

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

на устройстве 4.4 и эмуляторе 6.0 код работает, на 5.1 получаю null вместо номера телефона в строке `phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);`
 когда прекращается входящий вызов

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(INCOME_CALL_RECEIVE_ACTION)) {
        String phone_state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

        if (phone_state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

            Intent intentT = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            intentT.putExtra("phone", phoneNumber);

            intentT.putExtra(CONST_STATUS_CODE, CODE_INCOME_START);
            context.startService(intentT);
        }

        if (phone_state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {

            Intent intentT = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            intentT.putExtra("phone", phoneNumber);

            intentT.putExtra(CONST_STATUS_CODE, CODE_INCOME_STOP);
            context.startService(intentT);
        }
    }
}
```

в манифесте `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`
 и

Comment: Еще в манифесте у receiver -a   `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>`

Comment: Цель при входящем звонке, получить номер звонящего и передать в сервис, по факту окончания непринятого вызова также передать в сервис номер звонящего номера.

Comment: Причины мб разные, в зависимости какой intent вы принимаете как срабатывает Receive, его ограниченный период, как происходит работа в сервис, пермишн в манифесте, советую начать с того что просто в корне Receive прописать лог и увидите, что его поведение мб интересным, у меня есть пример который будет работать, сейчас напишу внизу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует слушатель по состояниям с callback, там есть номер который вам нужен.
Попробуйте так.

```
public class PhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, final String number) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, number);
            Log.d("onCallStateChanged", " === " + number);
        }
    }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!